# CKEditor 4 - How to add H2, H3, etc to toolbar

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Looking at these docs: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/styles.html

So adding a style set should go something like this, but I can't get the H2 or H3 items to appear in my toolbar:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles', [
    // Block-level styles
    { name: 'Blue Title', element: 'h2', styles: { 'color': 'Blue' } },
    { name: 'Red Title' , element: 'h3', styles: { 'color': 'Red' } },

    // Inline styles
    { name: 'CSS Style', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'my_style' } },
    { name: 'Marker: Yellow', element: 'span', styles: { 'background-color': 'Yellow' } }
] );


CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    
    config.extraPlugins = 'firstname,MediaEmbed,justify,image';
    
    //config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
    
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'iframe[*]';
    
    config.toolbar = 'Normal';
    
    config.toolbar_Normal = [
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic','Underline','Strike' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight' ] }        
    ];
    
    config.toolbar_Emails = [
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic','Underline','Strike' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight' ] }

    ];
    
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced;link:target';
    
    config.stylesSet = 'my_styles';

};
```

Comment: Have you tried `config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address;div';`? Check https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/format.html

Comment: Got me on the right track, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As mentioned in the [docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/format.html)

Open the `config.js` file available in your `ckeditor` directory, and edit the `config.format_tags` entry in the following way to display the text formatting toolbar.

```
// Enable all default text formats:
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address;div';

// Enable a limited set of text formats:
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;pre;div';
```

Answer (score 0):

We encountered an issue with the locally downloaded CKEditor library, and as a solution, we have opted to utilize the CKEditor library from an online Content Delivery Network (CDN). The code snippet provided below demonstrates the successful implementation:

`<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>`

`<textarea name="editor" id="editor" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>`

```
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
    toolbarGroups: [
      { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection' ] },
      { name: 'forms' },
      { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles' ] },
      { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
      { name: 'links' },
      { name: 'styles' }
    ],
    removeButtons: 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Styles',
    removeDialogTabs: 'link:advanced',
    format_tags: 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4',
    format_h1: { element: 'h1', name: 'Heading 1' },
    format_h2: { element: 'h2', name: 'Heading 2' },
    format_h3: { element: 'h3', name: 'Heading 3' },
    format_h4: { element: 'h4', name: 'Heading 4' }
  });
</script>
```